# What are the alternatives of a data class in java?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I am refactoring a car rental system code. The rental class keeps record of each rental duration, mileage, and car type. It has a method to compute final cost based on these attributes.

There are 3 (possibly more) car types with different daily prices. Checking each car type in the ComputeCost method is obviously not the best solution. However, polymorphism doesn't seem the appropriate solution either, since different car types don't implement extra functionality; they just have different rates. Moving the ComputeCost method to each of these subclasses doesn't also seem appropriate, since the method depends more on rental attributes like mileage and duration than on car type.

Comment: The major principle is DRY, don't repeat yourself. I am afraid your question can basically only be answered by yourself (too little code maybe). More code on [**code review**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) might help. BTW inheritance should be used sparely.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you really want a `Rate` class.

And that `Rate` class has a `computeCost(Rental)` method that computes the cost of a given rental with a given rate.

Now if *all* that's different between the different Rates are numerical values, then the `Rate` class can itself be a pretty basic class with a couple of fields.